# How can i stop (abort) an AsyncTask from another AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, mobile

I have a main activity that have 2 AsyncTask, I want one of those `AsyncTask` to abort the other `AsyncTask`.

```
class Contador extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
            httpclientContador = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String sContador = "http://webmilab.com/SEDESOL/index.php/transferencias/conteo/" + resIdEncuesta;

            pContador = new HttpPost(sContador);


            pContador.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            JSONObject jContador = new JSONObject();
            jContador.put("mensaje", "Empezar a contar :)");

            StringEntity eContador = new StringEntity("json="+jContador.toString(), "UTF-8");
            pContador.setEntity(eContador);
            httpclientContador.execute(pContador);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(TransferirDatos.this, "Hubo un error al realizar la petición del conteo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 

        }

    }

}
```

This is the AsyncTask that i want to finish.

```
class Contador extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Some Code

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 

        pContador.abort();  

    }

}
```

`HttpPost pContador` and `HttpClient httpclientContador` are variables define in the main activity.

When i try to execute this code the app always crashes, I want to know how can I abort the `AsyncTask` from the second `AsyncTask`.

Here is the Log.

```
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at tsp.consulting.TransferirDatos$Contador.doInBackground(TransferirDatos.java:184)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at tsp.consulting.TransferirDatos$Contador.doInBackground(TransferirDatos.java:1)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-08 09:22:48.625: E/AndroidRuntime(10950):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: Where are you getting youre pContador in the second class ? could you post the logs for the crash

Comment: HttpPost pContador is a global variable.

Comment: Did you initialized both AsyncTask classes in a global scope?

Comment: Yes i initialized both in a global scope, when i press i button both get initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are trying to print a Toast inside the doInBackground method.
This method is executed in a background thread, and thus it cannot interact with the UI.
You can read more on that here.

You can use the [onPostExecute(Result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method to notify the user after the task has ended, or the [onProgressUpdate(Progress...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) to update while the Task is running.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked without the Toast. Just one more question, when i abort the AsyncTask the onpostExecute is executed??

Comment: No, onPostExecute gets as a parameter the result of the onBackground, so if onBackground hasn't been called, onPostExecute is never called.

You can check out [onCancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled(Result)), but still will not be called in every case.